# Drawing QRect around QLine

Tags: c++, qt, algebra

This question is more about algebra than programming but maybe I will find some help here :) I am trying to create a QRect around a QLine with given offset(see picture below). Having the segment AB and the offset, how to find all the missing points to create a QRect?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

assuming you dont have a rotation then you can observe that:

your line is draw over two 2D points:
lets name those Pa and Pb

and more specifically

```
Pa is defined as Pa_x, Pa_y
Pb is defined as Pb_x, Pb_y
```

now:

```
the point F is located at Pa_x-X;Pa_y-X
the point D is located at Pb_x+X;Pb_y+X
```

in qt you can draw a rectangle with those 2 points

if rotation is included, then you can do a little trigonometry and use the cos(theta) sin(theta) to get those projections in the real x;y plane

Comment: Indeed I have to consider the rotation. Could you guide me a little bit more about using the trigonometry? Theta is the angle with the X axis?